# Lua/NSE socket connection problem

Tags: sockets, lua, nmap

I can telnet to a certain host and port no problem and issue commands. However when i try to script a socket connection (using nmap NSE and Lua) to the same host and port, it fails with the following error message:

`|_sockettest: Trying to receive through a closed socket`

the socket connect part of my code is here:

```
local msg
local response
msg = "hello\n"

local socket = nmap.new_socket()
socket:set_timeout(150000)
socket:send(msg)

response,data = socket:receive()
return data
```

I think the data is sending ok. The server should just echo back what i sent. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: I see no reason for the downvote. The underlying issue was a simple mistake, but the question had sufficient code to see the issue and resolve the problem. That is what SO is about and should be rewarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `socket:connect` before receiving (and before sending). Seriously, read that code you wrote. *Where* did you specify to whom you're sending ?